# Visual Studio shuts down when i open or create a project without any message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, shutdown

I m using Visual C# 2008 express edition .. when i open or create project in visual studio then Vs automatically shuts down automatically without any message .. this was also happend to me when i was using Visual studio 2008 ... i dont know whts happening ... i google it several times but cant fine revelant or proper answer ...  I reinstall Vs several times but problem is stilll there ... i scan my computer and there is no virus in it ..can any one plzz help me on this ..

Thanx in advance

Comment: Check the Event Viewer in Administrative Tools to see if a message is being logged there.

Comment: i m using Windows Vista Home premium ..

Comment: It has an event viewer too...

Comment: After installing VS2k8 did you run Windows Update and apply all the required patches (KBs & SPs)?

Comment: Perhaps the installation has corrupted. Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: yes i reinstall it several times ..

Comment: Sean ... i chekc event control and the message appeaer there is .. ".NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3603 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (6E87795E) (80131506)" how it resolve

Comment: Generic error.  Lots of google hits relating to plugins, drivers for hardware, etc.  If it was working and then started throwing this error, I'd determine if you'd installed some hardware, updates or new software, then roll those back.  If not, then I'd run memory tests and the like to see if there's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

check if `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcr90.dll` exists, or use dependency walker (depends.exe) on `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\VCSPackages\csproj.dll`

Answer (score 0):

`devenv.exe /safemode` or `devenv.exe /resetskippkgs`